# Unable to deploy Mule application using Azure Build pipeline

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mule

I am trying to build mule app and deploy to Anypoint platform Runtime manager, but getting the below error in "Maven@3" stage:

```
400 Bad Request
transfer-encoding: chunked
Server: nginx
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD
X-ANYPNT-TRX-ID: 1648f6e9-9b63-4850-9044-c8be0c96aeae
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2022 17:13:32 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, x-anypnt-env-id, x-anypnt-org-id
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-RateLimit-Remaining: unlimited
X-RateLimit-Limit: unlimited
Content-Type: application/json

{"status":400,"message":"{name=$(workerType), workerVal=null, cpu=null, memory=null} is not a valid value for worker.type.name."}
```

Below is the azure-pipeline.yml

```
    # Starter pipeline
    # Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
    # Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
    # https://aka.ms/yaml
    
    trigger:
    - dev
    
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    
    variables:
    - group: Build-Variable-Group
    - name: MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER
      value: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.m2/repository
    - name: MAVEN_OPTS
      value: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'
    
    
    steps:
    
    - task: CacheBeta@0
      inputs:
        key: pom.xml
        path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
      displayName: Cache Maven local Repo
    
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      name: settingsxml
      inputs:
        secureFile: 'settings.xml'
    
    - task: Powershell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
            New-Item -Type Directory -Force "${HOME}/.m2"
            Copy-Item -Force "$(settingsxml.secureFilePath)" "${HOME}/.m2/settings.xml"
            
            
    
    - task: Maven@3
      inputs:
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
        jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
        jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
        mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
        publishJUnitResults: false
        javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
        mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
        effectivePomSkip: true
        testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
        goals: 'clean install package deploy $(MAVEN_OPTS) -DmuleDeploy -Dserver=$(server) -Denvironment=$(environment) -Dworkers=$(workers) -DworkerType=$(workerType) -Dapp.runtime=$(app.runtime) -Dapp.name=$(app.name)'
```

and this is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>clx-ifa-workday-sys-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>

    <name>clx-ifa-workday-sys-api</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <app.runtime>4.4.0-20220221</app.runtime>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.6.3</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                <cloudHubDeployment>
                <uri>https://anypoint.mulesoft.com</uri>
                <server>${server}</server>
                <muleVersion>${app.runtime}</muleVersion>
                <applicationName>${app.name}</applicationName>
                <workers>${workers}</workers>
                <workerType>${workerType}</workerType>
                <environment>${environment}</environment>
                <objectStoreV2>true</objectStoreV2>
                
                </cloudHubDeployment>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-salesforce-connector</artifactId>
            <version>10.14.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange-v3</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v3/maven</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>test-ifa</id>
            <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CloroxDevOps/CLX-IFA-POC/_packaging/test-ifa/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>test-ifa</id>
            <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CloroxDevOps/CLX-IFA-POC/_packaging/test-ifa/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

tried changing mule-maven -plugin with some different version but unfortunately with every version same error coming.

my motto is build the jar file and deploy in DEV environment from Build pipeline

Comment: There is not enough information in the question for troubleshooting the error. Try adding the `-X` option to Maven so more details about the cause of the error are printed in the log.

Comment: edited the question with updated error

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status `400 Bad Request` indicates the request is incorrectly formed.

The error detail state the root cause:

```
{"status":400,"message":"{name=$(workerType), workerVal=null, cpu=null, memory=null} is not a valid value for worker.type.name."}
```

The pipeline is not setting a correct value for `workerType`.

Check that you are assigning a valid value to the properties defined in the command line. It appears that they are not defined in the variables section of the azure-pipeline.yml. Try set it to a valid value.